# Replace layout (refer to screenshot) created using HTML table with CSS with jQTouch

Tags: html, css, alignment, jqtouch

I'm trying to achieve something just like screenshot below using CSS.
Currently, it is implemented using HTML tables and as far as I know HTML table is usually not recommended.

What I want to achieve is:

- the date on right must be a vertically aligned, middle to the image on the left, just like the screenshot
- there is a gap between each photo (which right now I can only think of `<br/>`)
- every image and dates are supposed to be different too.

[image: Screenshot of what I want to achieve]

HTML below:

wrapper and scroller are iScroll CSS classes.

```
<div id="wrapper">
                <div id="scroller">


                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var i=0;
                        for (i=0;i<=20;i++)
                        {   
                            document.write('<table>');
                            document.write('<tr>');
                            document.write('<td><img src="gimages/photo1.JPG" width="50%"></td>');
                            document.write('<td>11 December 2011</td>');
                            document.write('</tr>');
                            document.write('</table>');
                        }                           
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: do you have a demo site or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? or at least some of your code?

Comment: hi @Joseph, inserted the html codes.

Comment: are you selectively populating data from database? or, which server side language you are using? php? ruby?

Comment: @KMC. I'm intending to retrieve the data in form of JSON using jQuery. The codes above are just sample. I'm quite sure how to write the JS algorithms, just finding it tough to get the presentation right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list `<ul>` and `<li>`, don't use list-style-image, use background image instead:

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <ul class="myul">
            <li id="first">11 December 2011</li>
            <li id="second">11 December 2011</li>
            <li id="third">11 December 2011</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
.myul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.myul li {
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0;
}
.myul li#first {
    background-image: url(temp.png);
}
.myul li#third {
    background-image: url(temp.png);
}
</style>
```

[image]

[EDIT]

Unlike class, id must be unique. You can assign both class and id attribute to a tag. Above is an example to give an image to the first and third list, but not the second. All first, second and third contains style defined in the class ".myul li".

Comment: hi @KMC, will it be possible to load each image from a different image file?

Comment: yep! all the images will be different.

Comment: Hi, I'm quite unfamilar with CSS. How should I seperate the background-image to id ?

Comment: I've another question! Gosh. I realized another css I have is overwritting the CSS that you gave me. How should I force the HTML to use the CSS the specific CSS i used?

Comment: one trick you can use is to put the <style> content outside and AFTER the </html> tag instead. See edited answer.

Comment: Hi @KMC, thanks your answers. I realized my question was too vague but you did provide me some direction to work towards. I also posted a [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695805/how-to-achieve-layout-with-jqtouch-and-iscroll-library) question which is more reflective of what I was look for.